# SEO implications of invalid XML for Strict DOCTYPE

Tags: xhtml, seo, doctype, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm working on some search engine optimizations on a variety of websites and have noticed that a number of them contain invalid XHTML and are using the XHTML 1.0 Strict DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I wonder how much (if at all) this would affect search engines. Any relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Cutts from Google said no in 2009. I'd suspect their stance has not changed:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBACTS-tyg

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize they had all those videos up there. I'll be sure to check them out.